# VS 17 breaking on all exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 is (kind of suddenly) breaking on *all* exceptions. That means, if I deactivate them in the exceptions settings (pressing CTRL + ALT + E while debugging), the debugger still breaks on them. I don't know wether this is just a bug of VS I can't change and therefore have to live with, or wether there is a simple solution for it.

This is the exception settings window:
[image: the exception settings]

and this the exception VS breaks on:
[image: the exception]

By the way, I also tried that beautiful minus (nothing happens if I press it) or adding a impossible condition (VS still broke on the exception).

I also tested other exceptions (by simply throwing them), which I deactivated before, and they get thrown as well and I tested the same issue in other projects, where it appeared as well:
[image: the issue in other projects]

I actually even put the whole stuff into a try catch statement but VS still breaks:

```
InitializeComponent ();
try
{
    var t = new Thread (() =>
    {
        while (!IsHandleCreated) {} //It breaks here (similiar to the screenshots)
        while (true)
            Invoke (new Action (() => Size = new Size ()));
    });
    while (true)
    {
        t.Start ();
        Thread.Sleep (100);
        t.Abort ();
    }
}
catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
```

It doesn't appear in other IDEs (like Rider) on my PC and doesn't occurr on other PCs in VS. It didn't always occurr on my PC, it just started recently and only in debugging mode. And if I continue the execution (with F5) it just continues normally.

**EDIT** As I put the try catch inside the thread it behaved a little bit different (I'm sorry for putting pictures in here, but I think they're more expressive in that case):
[image: new exception location]

Can *anybody* explain this behaviour?

**EDIT** It seems to be normal for `ThreadAbortExceptions` to break again at the end of a catch statement. However, VS still shouldn't break on this exception at all.

Comment: as side note : your try catch should be inside thread that is created, currently your try catch is on UI thread and there is no exception there to be caught...

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I edited my question

Comment: Look - sometimes it's just too time expensive to try to find and explain the bug in cases like these where you can't reproduce it in a way that is "normal". (1) try rebooting and (2) revert back to your previous code and build up to that point. Yeah yeah I know my comment isn't an "answer", but you can spend hours and days fruitlessly tracking this one thing down - better to just move on.

Comment: @rlb.usa already tried multiple reboots and as you can see other code (I actually created a new project) doesn't work either, so why should it work to revert back to previous code? I mean, it's ok, I can live with the possibility that this is just another bug of VS, I was just curious, wether somebody has a solution. It is just immensively annoying, as I raise this exception quite often totally conscious.

Comment: you can open question about this on `msdn.microsoft.com` or report bug by selecting icon on top of VS i.e `send feedback` and then `report a problem`, if this is really a bug in VS then you have better chance to solve this there

Comment: @MetaColon, If I put the whole stuff into a try catch statement, I will get the Exception "Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart" like this case: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ee0702ee-444e-4b05-86af-a809ee5fbc96/thread-is-running-or-terminated-it-cannot-restart?forum=csharpgeneral, like M.kazem Akhgary's suggestion, if possible, you could report it to the develop community site: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html .

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I'm aware of the exception, which gets thrown in your case (the cannot restart exception). However, in my case the threadAbortException breaks VS first. I'll report it to the develop community as suggested.

Comment: Apart from the subject. What's name of this extension You're using for colorizing syntax?

Comment: @p__d Resharper Ultimate.

Comment: @MetaColon，Since you have submitted this report here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/73973/vs-2017-breaking-on-all-exceptions.html, maybe we could get better suggestion from the product team directly.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT that means? Where should I report it?

Comment: @MetaColon, You don't need to report it, it has been report to the develop community site as the link in my previous comment, I also help you vote it, the product team members will view and provide the suggestion in that report directly. Just follow up that report:)

Comment: Same problem. Never happened in VS 2015. Exception settings are being completely ignored in VS 2017. Not really surprising considering it is MS garbage.

Comment: Same issue, came up with code copied directly from .NET API doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library

Comment: To help you find bugs, you should only disable specific exceptions and only when not in your code… and write code that does not throw exceptions for normal condition. If you really want to use exceptions for expected conditions, use your own exception class so you can disable "break on exception" only from that class and know that you won't miss a break due to a bug in your software.

Comment: I came across this exception missbehavior also by using InvalidOperationException in my own code. I have disabled "Break When Thrown" and still getting stopped here, that's very tedious. I also set "Continue When…" doens't matter for VS(ENTERPRISE!)2017  :(

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar problem.

I fixed it by unchecking *"Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries"* in **Tools > Options > Debugging > General**

Comment: As it happens I don't use VS anymore (I use Rider instead), so I won't be able to test it. Maybe somebody else can test it, so I can mark this as an answer if it works.

Comment: I tried this solution and it does solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I can't confirm whether this happens with other project types, but it happens to me consistently with (Visual Studio Tools for Python) VSTP.

Although it is less than satisfactory, it can at least silence the exceptions and allow you to continue working in peace until a better solution surfaces. In my case, it was nearly impossible to debug my code, since StopIteration breaks during every iteration.

Select *Debug > Windows > Exception Setting*s or press **Ctrl-Alt-E**.  Y

[image: Exception Settings]

Right click anywhere on the Window and select *Show Columns > Additional Actions*.  You will have an "Additional Actions" column appear if it doesn't already.

Right click on a specific exception you want to silence or click the top level checkbox to select an entire category of exceptions, i.e. *Python Exceptions*. Click *Continue When Unhandled in User Code*.

Repeat for each additional exception or category of exceptions.

Comment: As it happens I don't use VS anymore (I use Rider instead), so I won't be able to test it. Maybe somebody else can test it, so I can mark this as an answer if it works.

Comment: What do you think about rider?  Is it as snappy?  Is it JRE based?

Comment: As this is primarily opinion based, it doesn't quite belong here, but I like it very much and have no idea wether it's JRE based or not.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by unchecking `Enable Just My Code` in Tools > Options > Debugging > General

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late for this, but ThreadAbortException is different from all other exceptions, and requires some special handling, otherwise it is automatically re-thrown at the end of all catch blocks if you don't actually handle it the way it's supposed to be handled.

Comment: But I'm with MetaColon that when you disable "Break When Thrown" Option in Exception Settings, there shouldn't be a break.