# Visual Studio 2017 Breaks on System.InvalidOperationException Even Though It Is Both Handled AND Unchecked In Exception Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Like the title says, I have some code where I expect to run into a `System.InvalidOperationException`.  Additionally the code is catching/handling the exception.

Furthermore, under Exception Settings, the box for `System.InvalidOperationException` is unchecked.

Yet, without fail Visual Studio breaks on that exception when debugging, whether in a `Debug` profile or `Release` profile.

[image]

[image]

FYI: I've searched and searched and searched for something about this, but it seems everything I've come across was either about not breaking on certain exceptions when actually wanting to, or breaking on purposefully thrown exceptions. Hadn't found anything on the above sadly...

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790784/vs-17-breaking-on-all-exceptions?noredirect=1 ?

Comment: @Fab I did not, but that solved it. Can I mark my own question as a duplicate, or just delete it?  Thanks by the way!

Comment: uncheck `Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries` in `Tools > Options > Debugging > General`

Comment: @DanielA.Burke can be marked as duplicate as it is just a different way to ask the question.